# How to remove a part of a string with variable?

Tags: macos, bash

I just got into bash so I decided to write my first script. To give you a little background I want to write a script that will back up my Documents folder onto a USB stick whenever I connect the USB stick. (I am aware that software like this exists).

I have two strings at the beginning of the script:

```
directoryPath="/Users/USER/Documents" # Folder I want to backup
backupPath="/Volumes/backMeUp/main" # Where I want the folder to backup
```

For loops gives me absolute path to a file like this

```
/Users/USER/Documents/Comics/Bleach/Volume 004/bleach_031.zip
```

Until now I was using sed like this

```
newPath=`echo "$file" | sed "/Users\/USER\/Documents/s//Volumes\/backMeUp\/main/"`
```

But since I want my script to be more "open" and other-user-friendly I want to get rid of this line and make it some other way.

I also tried this with different syntax

```
echo $file | sed -e "s/$directoryPath/$backupPath/"
```

but with no luck.

**My question is how can I remove part of a string with $directoryPath and replace it with $backupPath?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>[`basename`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename) (and [`dirname`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirname)) are your friend(s).</strike>

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

directoryPath="/Users/rojcyk/Documents" # Folder I want to backup
backupPath="/Volumes/backMeUp/main" # Where I want the folder to backup

f=$(basename '/Users/rojcyk/Documents/Comics/Bleach/Volume 004/bleach_031.zip')

echo ${backupPath}/${f}
```

**Updated**

```
#!/bin/bash

directoryPath="/Users/rojcyk/Documents" # Folder I want to backup
backupPath="/Volumes/backMeUp/main" # Where I want the folder to backup

f='/Users/rojcyk/Documents/Comics/Bleach/Volume 004/bleach_031.zip'

# delete shortest match of substring from front of string
new_f=${f#$directoryPath}

echo ${backupPath}${new_f}
```

Output:

```
/Volumes/backMeUp/main/Comics/Bleach/Volume 004/bleach_031.zip
```

Read more about bash string operations [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

Comment: Yeah, this is what I wanted! :) The thing is the Documents folder is also structured so I want the output to be something like this:/Volumes/backMeUp/main/Comics/Bleach/Volume 004/bleach_031.zip

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
directoryPath="/Users/rojcyk/Documents"
backupPath="/Volumes/backMeUp/main"
f="/Users/rojcyk/Documents/Comics/Bleach/Volume 004/bleach_031.zip"

echo "${backupPath}/${f#$directoryPath}"
```

Produces

```
/Volumes/backMeUp/main//Comics/Bleach/Volume 004/bleach_031.zip
```

The double slash in the middle is OK. If you don't want it: `"${backupPath}/${f#$directoryPath/}"`

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
kent$  cat t
$foo$bar$blah

kent$  sed 's/\$foo/\$xxx/g' t
$xxx$bar$blah
```

or this?

```
kent$  echo $foo
/f/o/o

kent$  echo $bar
/b/a/r

kent$  cat t
something /f/o/o

kent$  sed "s:$foo:$bar:" t
something /b/a/r
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -e "s/$directoryPath/$backupPath/"
```

You're on the right path, just need to manipulate the two path variables first.

The contents of `$directoryPath` is `/Users/rojcyk/Documents`, so your sed command is coming out as `sed -e "s//Users/rojcyk/Documents//Volumes/backMeUp/main/"`. You need to escape the directory slashes so they don't affect the sed command.

Try this:

```
directoryPathEscaped=`echo $directoryPath | sed -e "s/\\//\\\\\\\\\//g"`
backupPathEscaped=`echo $backupPath| sed -e "s/\\//\\\\\\\\\//g"`
# At this point, directoryPathEscaped is equal to "\/Users\/rojcyk\/Documents"

# Now you can do your original command line, with the new variables.
sed -e "s/$directoryPathEscaped/$backupPathEscaped/"
```

Comment: Thank you :) But I want my code to be easy to understand so I want to avoid using commands like yours sed.

Comment: Actually the proper solution is to use a different separator. Ideally, find a character which does not occur in your data. Maybe colon? `sed "s:$directoryPath:$backupPath:"`